# Converted garage flooding

Tags: water

We recently bought a house that had the garage converted into a bedroom.

When it rains water comes up through the floor near where the garage door would have been.

We have noticed that water tends to pool near the exterior corner of that room.

What would be the best way to determine  where the water is coming from in order to fix it ?

Comment: You've given us a drinking straw to look through to solve a complex problem. Please revise with photos or a much better description of the situation. Exterior grade, roof drainage, and other factors are all important.

Comment: is the ground outside that wall lower than the floor?

Comment: I agree with @isherwood there are a few of us that have done these types of conversions , even things like is the door still there or is it a wall replacing the door would be helpful.